# How to use ArcGIS VRP Service with numerous stops on single route?

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I am trying to optimize a route using [ArcGIS VRP REST Service](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/index.html#/Vehicle_Routing_Problem_Service/02r3000000n4000000/).

I have a situation where I want to solve for a single route with more than 200 orders (approx. 1000) with only one depot at the end of route.

The API has limitation of max. 200 orders per route.

Is there any any work around or any other appropriate solution?

Answer (score 0):

When using services from Esri, such as the routing service, you're stuck with the limit they place -- in this case, 200 orders per route.

The only solution I am aware of is to create and use your own network analyst service on a local ArcGIS Server.